# Assertion ` l !=NULL' failed with List

Tags: c, list, struct, assert

I'm implementing a chained list structure in C, but i've got an assertion error : *Assertion `l!=NULL' failed.* Whereas, i'm not suppose to have it.

Here is my structure :

```
typedef struct list list;
struct list{
  element * elt;
  list * next;
};
```

Here is my add method :

```
int add(char* user, list*l){
  if(l==NULL){
    printf("NULL %s\n", user);
    l=malloc(sizeof(list));
    l->elt=malloc(sizeof(element));
    (l->elt)->username=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    strcpy((l->elt)->username,user);
    (l->elt)->score=0;
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    printf("not NULL %s\n", user);
    return add(user,l->next);
  }
}
```

And here is the main :

```
int main(){
  list * l ;
  assert(l==NULL);
  printf("%d\n", add("hello",l));
  assert(l!=NULL);
  return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Changing `l` in the function does not change `l` in main, it is a copy. Also `l` in main is not initialized.

Comment: @venilla Your `list` will not be formed since you are locally making changes which get destroyed when `add` function ends. You should either return the list pointer from `add` funtion or send 2d pointer to make changes in main.

Comment: The variable `l` is never assigned to, nor is it initialized, so one of those two `assert` calls is bound to fail. Also, since the variable has no explicitly defined value when it is read, the program has _undefined behavior_.

Comment: FWIW, this is exactly the sort of thing that assertions are for.

Comment: Off topic, but... in many fonts, `l` and `1` are hard to distinguish so it is wise to avoid using `l` as a variable/parameter name.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck MISRA-C:2012 actually includes a directive banning the use of `l` for identifiers for that very reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to pointer for list in order to change it's content in a function.

```
int add(char* user, list**l){
  if((*l)==NULL){
    printf("NULL %s\n", user);
    (*l)=malloc(sizeof(list));
    (*l)->elt=malloc(sizeof(element));
    ((*l)->elt)->username=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    strcpy(((*l)->elt)->username,user);
    ((*l)->elt)->score=0;
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    printf("not NULL %s\n", user);
    return add(user,&((*l)->next));
  }
}
```

and function call must be like

```
  list *l = NULL; //pointer is allocated, points to nothing for now
  printf("%d\n", add("hello",&l));
```

Comment: `l` also should be initialised to `NULL`.

Comment: yes you are right, otherwise *l == NULL would never work. thank you i will edit

Comment: I tried you solution, but i got this warning : 
_warning: passing argument 2 of ‘add’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return add(user,(*l)->next);_

Comment: and this one : 
_note: expected ‘list ** {aka struct list **}’ but argument is of type ‘struct list *’
 int add(char* user, list**l)_

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the address of `l` to the function `add`.
Also I see that you have not initialized the local variable. The first assertion is not required. 
Call your function like this:
`printf("%d\n", add("hello",&l));`

Change the function prototype
to `int add(char* user, list**l)` and modify your function accordingly.